Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: With Moq
I am getting an error
Moq.MockException : 
Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: m => m.Position = Vector

Performed invocations:

   Mock<IMove:1> (m):

      IMove.Position
      IMove.Velocity
      IMove.Position = Vector

and below is the my code structure
using Moq;

namespace Lab1.Test
{
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Move_from_12_5_to_5_8_with_velocity_N7_3()
        {
            var move = new Mock<IMove>();

            move.SetupGet(m => m.Position).Returns(new Vector( 12, 5)).Verifiable();
            move.SetupGet(m => m.Velocity).Returns(new Vector( -5, 3)).Verifiable();

            ICommand moveCommand = new CMove(move.Object);

            moveCommand.Execute();

            move.VerifySet(m => m.Position = new Vector( 5, 8), Times.Once);
            move.VerifyAll();
        }
    }
}

and tested classes
 public class Vector
 {
   private int[] coordinates;
   private int coord_cont;
   public Vector(params int[] coordinates)
   {
     this.coordinates = coordinates;
     this.coord_cont = coordinates.Length;
   }
   public static Vector operator +(Vector a, Vector b)
   {
     Vector c = new(new int[a.coord_cont]);
     c.coordinates = (a.coordinates.Select((x, index) => x + b.coordinates[index]).ToArray());
     return c;
   }

   public override bool Equals(object? obj)
   {
     if (obj == null || obj is not Vector)
       return false;
     else
       return coordinates.SequenceEqual(((Vector)obj).coordinates);
   }

   public override int GetHashCode()
   {
     return coordinates.GetHashCode();
   }
 }

public interface IMove
{
  public Vector Position { get; set; }
  public Vector Velocity { get; }
}


public class CMove : ICommand
{
    private readonly IMove move;
    public CMove(IMove move)
    {
        this.move = move;
    }
    public void Execute()
    {
      move.Position += move.Velocity;
    }
}

I want to use Moq as a layout for interface tests. But when i try use VerifySet, i get an error.
i try make a simple example of the using moq.
i don't understand why invocation on the mock was 0 times/
I tried to find a solution on the internet, but I didn’t find any similar case

You have more time and code invested in using moq than code actually under test. Are you sure that is what you want?

Why did you expect Vector( 5, 8)? Shouldn't this be Vector( 7, 8)?

Yes, I believe the velocity should be (-7,3) to result in (5,8)

BTW: your implementation of Vector.GetHashCode is wrong. It is required that objects comparing equal (as of the Equals method) have the same hash.

Please, change row
move.VerifySet(m => m.Position = new Vector( 5, 8), Times.Once);

to
move.VerifySet(m => m.Position = new Vector(7,8), Times.Once);

Because 12 - 5 is indeed 7, not 5 :)
I would recommend you to use constants in test to omit possibility of same mistakes in future. For example you could write your test like that:
using Moq;
using Xunit;

namespace Lab1.Test
{
    public class CMoveTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Move_Works_Correctly()
        {
            //Arrange
            var move = new Mock<IMove>();

            var vec1 = new Vector(12, 5);
            var vec2 = new Vector(-5, -3);

            move.SetupGet(m => m.Position).Returns(vec1).Verifiable();
            move.SetupGet(m => m.Velocity).Returns(vec2).Verifiable();

            ICommand moveCommand = new CMove(move.Object);
            
            //Act
            moveCommand.Execute();

            //Assert
            move.VerifySet(m => m.Position = vec1 + vec2, Times.Once);
            move.VerifyAll();
        }
    }
}


If possible I would vote against any computation inside the assertions.
